# Automation Testing with Ranorex

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, php, ranorex

I am new to automation testing.

I am testing my web application (php) using ranorex automation tool. Whenever I record my test case, it is recording perfectly but when I play my test case it stops(sometimes get hanged) at the middle and fail my test case.

What is the reason that is creating this issue? Also, can anybody suggest good video tutorials for beginners for Data driven testing with global parameters?

Comment: Do you get an error message? What did you try to solve this? What are you trying to test. To give a good answer we need much more context.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the test playback does not wait long enough for the element to appear, but as you do not give a lot of info about what your are testing and how its a bit of guessing work.

I would read up on how to wait for elements with Ranorex: http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/test-automation-code-examples.html#c3197

Answer (score 0):

Please view these videos : https://www.youtube.com/user/RanorexChannel/videos

First you practice in different test suite's functional testing.

Then learn about different testing Frame work (Data Driven Testing,Hybrid Testing, Keyword-Driven Testing ) and start testing.

Visit these sites

1. http://www.ranorex.com/support/screencasts.html
   2.http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-3-data-driven-testing.html